# How do I enable night mode in display of Xubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, display, gnome-control-center

I am using Xubuntu 16.04

In Ubuntu there is the option to enable night mode from **Display** in **Gnome Control Center**

In my Xubuntu I have installed **Gnome Control Center**

But over there the **Display** option shows

**Could not get Screen Information**

So how can I enable night mode in my Xubuntu?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following instructions will not enable gnomes night mode. But will allow a nearly indistinguishable effect.

**Install redshift**

`sudo apt-get install redshift redshift-gtk`

**Edit GeoClue's config**

`sudo nano /etc/geoclue/geoclue.conf`

Append the following lines to `/etc/geoclue/geoclue.conf`

```
[redshift]
allowed=true
system=false
users=
```

**Configure redshift**

Example of a manual config, for Copenhagen, Denmark. See [Redshift homepage](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) for an additional config example. Comment out or change the latitude and longitude for you location.
`nano ~/.config/redshift.conf`

```
[redshift]
temp-day=6500
temp-night=3700
location-provider=manual

[manual]
lat=55.7
lon=12.6
```

Comment: In your answer you have not mention whether latitude is N or S and also whether longitude is E or W. How to mention so?

Comment: South or west would be denoted by a negative latitude or longitude. For instance Lima, Peru would be `lat=-12.0` `lon=-77.0`

Comment: Do I really need to setup `GeoClue` if I define the location in the `redshift.conf` manually?

Comment: One method or the other will do. For a laptop geoclue may be advantageous as it would adjust for different locations

Comment: Solid this works for xubuntu where I was having issues before. Thanks.